# MYSQL 3 tables has amount column sum

Tags: mysql

Mysql sum 3 column different tables

Table list below

### budget

### |b_id  |amount     |

|     1|        100|
|     2|        200|

---

### cash_advance

### |ca_id |b_id  |ca_amount |

|     1|     1|    100   |
|     2|     2|    200   |

---

### expenses

### |exp_id|ca _id|exp_amount|

|     1|     1|       100|
|     2|     2|        40|
|     3|     2|       160|

i want this result

### resul

### |sum(b_amount)|sum(ca_amount)|sum(exp_amount)|

|     100|    100|   100|
|     200|    200|   200|

any mysql query? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the network on your UI thread. This is bad because it will freeze the UI until the network response has returned. You should do this network access on a separate thread.

There are many options, but the simplest option would be:

Convert msg in MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); to be final.
Wrap Transport.send(msg); as new Thread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { Transport.send(msg); } }).start();

Answer (score 1):

The log is indicating that you're doing network tasks on your main thread, the UI / Activity thread. Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for those tasks instead.

Android forbids those tasks on your main thread, because they block the UI and make it unusable until your task is finished.

Answer (score 0):

In android 3.0  and higher network connection on the main thread isnt permitted, strictMode is turned on automatically.

To fix this issue, you must perform the network connection on a separate thread... for example, using an `AsyncTask`, `Threads`, `Handler`.